# I'm receiving this message error - Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in

Tags: php, arguments, warnings, array-merge

**In this line i found this:**

The line of this problem is `themify-shoppe/admin/post-type-product.php` on line 731:

```
 /**
 * Add woocommerce_enable_ajax_add_to_cart option to JS
 * @param Array
 * @return Array
 */

 function themify_woocommerce_params($params){
     return array_merge($params, array(
        "option_ajax_add_to_cart" => ('yes'== get_option('woocommerce_enable_ajax_add_to_cart') )? 'yes': 'no'
        ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace that code with this:

```
/**
 * Add woocommerce_enable_ajax_add_to_cart option to JS
 * @param Array
 * @return Array
 */
function themify_woocommerce_params($params){
    if(is_array($params)){
        return array_merge($params, array(
            'option_ajax_add_to_cart' => ( 'yes' == get_option('woocommerce_enable_ajax_add_to_cart') )? 'yes': 'no'
        ) );
    }else{
        return array(
            'option_ajax_add_to_cart' => ( 'yes' == get_option('woocommerce_enable_ajax_add_to_cart') )? 'yes': 'no'
        );
    }
}
```

Edit this code in Themify by going to your WP Dashboard -> Appearance -> Editor -> theme_functions.php

Visit [debugman.in](http://www.debugman.in/how-to-fix/) to know more about it.